# Trying to create a print page that only shows 3 divs

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to write a code that hides all elements of a page besides three divs. It is so people will have a printer friendly version. I wrote it in jQuery but (it is political with our vendor) it will not work.

Here is the code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>function prntz(){
document.getElementsByTagName("body").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("hider").style.display = "inline";
document.getElementById("hider1").style.display = "inline";
document.getElementById("hider2").style.display = "inline"; 
};</script>
```

Where the prntz function is called upon clicking a button. I have been able to make the divs display, but striping everything is not working. any ideas?

I feel like I am using the getElementsByTagName incorrectly but I am unsure.

Comment: [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getElementsByTagName) returns a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *are* using `getElementsByTagName` incorrectly (it returns a `NodeList`, which doesn't have a `style` property), but that's just preventing your having a different problem: If you hide `body`, it doesn't matter what you do with anything *inside* `body`, it won't show.

This is much better handled with CSS, using a print style sheet:

```
@media print {
    /* ...rules to show and hide things here...*/;
}
```

What I'd probably do is use a class to hide anything you don't want printed. In fact, I've been known to use two classes: `print` and `no-print`. `print` means "I only want to see this when printing" and `no-print` means "I only want to see this when *not* printing". Anything that doesn't have one class or the other is shown both on-screen and when printing. You use it only with the top-level of the thing in question.

The rules look like this:

```
@media not print {
    .print {
        display: none;
    }
}
@media print {
    .no-print {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Example: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/tulan/1)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Example</title>
  <style>
    @media not print {
      .print {
        display: none;
      }
    }
    @media print {
      .no-print {
        display: none;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Shows both on-screen and when printing</p>
  <p class="print">Shows only when printing</p>
  <p class="no-print">Shows only when <strong>not</strong> printing</p>
</body>
</html>
```

On screen, you see this:

```
Shows both on-screen and when printing

Shows only when not printing
```

When printing, you see this:

```
Shows both on-screen and when printing

Shows only when printing
```

Note the `strong` element in the example. Its visibility is determined by its container.

Comment: It is now taking out the body but, it doesn't bring the divs back into the page

Comment: @user3870118: It would appear that five seconds after the comment above, you accepted the answer -- did you figure out what was going on that wasn't bringing the other elements back on the page?

Comment: No, I accepted the answer because it seems like this would be the correct way to do it. I just cannot figure out why it will not bring the divs back in

Comment: @user3870118: Gotcha. Probably un-accept until we sort that out (other people are unlikely to answer questions with an accepted answer). Meanwhile, let me see if I can throw together an example.

Comment: @user3870118: Happy to help. I've updated the answer with an approach I've used in a production environment that's worked well for us.

Answer (score 0):

All of the elements inside a hidden element will be hidden, so by setting `display: none` on the body, all of the divs inside the body will also be hidden.

An alternative would be to use a print type sheet, for example:

```
/* hide all divs */
div { display: none; }

/* show the hider divs, and the divs inside them */
#hider, #hider2, #hider3,
#hider div, #hider2 div, #hider3 div { display: block; }
```

Comment: Thank you, I will take this into consideration as well